# How to delete gpg secret keys by force, without fingerprint?

Tags: batch, gnupg

It's accident generated a bulk of secret keys (without public key) in the GPG key ring, 
and I have written a script to delete those keys, but GPG doesn't allow me to do that:

```
$ gpg --batch --yes --delete-secret-keys KEYS
gpg: can't do this in batch mod
gpg: (unless you specify the key by fingerprint)
```

well I know what I'm doing and I know there may be duplicated key-id(s), but there seems no way to force to delete them, though the following doesn't work, too:

```
$ yes | gpg --delete-secret-keys KEYS
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `gpg --list-secret-keys --with-colons --fingerprint` to generate the list of fingerprints in an easily parsable format. Grab the lines of the form `fpr:::::::::xxxx:` that correspond to the keys you want to delete, and pass the fingerprints (the *`xxxx`*) to `gpg --batch --delete-secret-keys`.

The following command generates all secret key fingerprints. Be sure to select only the ones you want to delete!

```
gpg --list-secret-keys --with-colons --fingerprint | sed -n 's/^fpr:::::::::\([[:alnum:]]\+\):/\1/p'
```

Comment: Great! I thought the fingerprint is only available in public keys.

Comment: Oops! I'm wrong, the fingerprint couldn't be fetched from, the command yeilds:

    gpg: key XXXXXXXX: secret key without public key - skipped
    gpg: error reading key: secret key not availble

In fact, I'm just wondering why `yes | ...' doesn't work, and I think the only way is patch on gpg. Thanks

Comment: This commands output 2 fingerprints. The subkey fingerprint is deleted when the "primary" is deleted. Maybe that's why you get that error?

Comment: Can I pipe into `| xargs gpg --delete-key` to delete all?

Answer (score 3):

I know this topic is old, and that the answer kinda looks like Gilles one, but I think it answers the question totally (since I had the same kind of problems as OP) :

```
for i in `gpg --with-colons --fingerprint | grep "^fpr" | cut -d: -f10`; do gpg --batch --delete-secret-keys "$i" ; done
```

Comment: Does not work. Please check your syntax

Comment: It works for me. What is your output?

Comment: This works for me thanks for the command

Answer (score 2):

I combined the answers by Gilles and Dolanor into this one liner that is useful in case you want to delete a specific key:

```
gpg --fingerprint --with-colons ${GPG_KEY} |\
    grep "^fpr" |\
    sed -n 's/^fpr:::::::::\([[:alnum:]]\+\):/\1/p' |\
    xargs gpg --batch --delete-secret-keys
```

Not answering the original question, but might be useful for someone else.

Comment: But still we need to supply $GPG_KEY.

Comment: Maybe use `${GPG_KEY:-hey-user-you-forgot-something-to-set}` instead... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Export the keys you want to keep, delete the file and then recreate your ring.

Comment: I'd rather prefer to patch & recompile gpg.